# Fail2ban and X-Forwarded

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, fail2ban, x-forwarded-for

I am configuring fail2ban on my webservers. My Webservers are behind ELB. so I configured X-forwarded to get the real IP's in Apache Access logs.But unfortunately fail2ban not able scan accesslogs when x-forwarded is enabled in access logs.This is my regress condition

```
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*\"(GET|POST).*
```

And bellow is my logformat when x-forwarded enabled

```
10.0.2.18 (42.104.63.31) - - [01/May/2014:16:05:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/537.75.14"
```

Answer (score 2):

Part of your problem is that you are pulling out the wrong `<HOST>`. Your `^<HOST>` will match a `<HOST>` when found at the beginning of the like e.g. 10.0.2.18 when I guess what you really want is 42.104.63.31. You can fix this by telling fail2ban to look for `<HOST>` inside `()` e.g.

```
failregex=\(<HOST>\) -.*(GET|POST)
```

which seems to work when run through fail2ban-regex with your log snippet

```
fail2ban-regex logsnippet '\(<HOST>\) -.*(GET|POST)'

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : \(<HOST>\) -.*(GET|POST)
Use         log file : logsnippet


Results
=======

Failregex: 1 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1] \(<HOST>\) -.*(GET|POST)
|      42.104.63.31  Thu May 01 16:05:39 2014
`-
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it is able to read client IP's But Getting this warning again and again.  �<28>fail2ban.filter : WARNING Unable to find a corresponding IP address for -

Comment: ailregex=\(<HOST>\) -.*(GET|POST)
But Still not blacklisting Ip with the above rule.

With these it blocks IP's without xoforwarded logs..
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*\"(GET|POST).*